# how to give the height dynamically to iframe

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading cross domain page url through iframe in my site. like below

```
<iframe class="iframeId" src="cross domain... /view/id/100" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I want set height for iframe after loading the page
If I use below code getting some error for cross domain url

```
$('.iframeId').load(function () {
    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```

the error is **"Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'"**.
My aim is to load the page in iframe without scroll bars.
So how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: try this $(this).outerHeight(true); or $(this).css("height");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issue here. You have no access to the `iframe` if it is **not** from the same domain as parent document. You can't change its style neither DOM.
However, if you are able to develop the content of the URL pointed by iframe you can try with `message` event and `postMessage` method. Your parent document could do

```
$('#iframeId').load(function () {
    $('#iframeId').get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('requestHeightChange', '*');
});
```

Then the document in `iframe` should listen to `message` event

```
$(window).on('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    if (!data) data = e.originalEvent.data;
    if ("requestHeightChange" == data) {
        window.parent.postMessage("setHeight:" + document.body.offsetHeight, "*");
    }
});
```

Your parent document should also listen to `message` event and since, there's no distinction between which message comes from which iframe, you must provide it in the message `data`. `event.data` is the only data possible to be sent by `postMessage`. Parent's event listener might look like this:

```
$(window).on('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    if (!data) data = e.originalEvent.data;
    data = data.split(":");
    if ("setHeight" == data[0]) {
        $('#iframeId').height(data[1] + "px");
    }
});
```

To learn more about `postMessage` refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Answer (score 0):

You can't resolve this problem if you don't have access to both domains.
Think about the security holes if you were able to do that.

If you do have access to both domains the trick is to pass the proper height from one domain to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change or access properties of `iframe` loaded from other domain due to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

Could you please try below....

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('.iframeId').height($(document).height());
>     }); 
> </script>
```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**